# Reword no longer reproduced close reason wording

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

There seems to be a small loophole that certain questions are getting past this close reason with. While the wording of the close reason states that questions resolved in a manner unlikely to help future visitors is a valid use, it is obstructed by being so deep in the description.

Here is the current description of the close reason (emphasis verbatim)

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

However, in my opinion this wording does a small disservice to the resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. The tense used with "this one was resolved" implies that the problem was already solved, which means users already wasted time on something which will be closed and deleted.

Moreover, it is apparent that questions [specific to one person's lack of understanding of a basic language feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355245/1026459) are [undesirable, yet at present rather uncloseable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355251/1026459). I believe that this close reason could be used for those, as [@Sayse suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355317/1026459).

It just needs to be worded a little clearer so users know that their question was closed as a result of its resolution being unlikely to help future readers.

So, I propose modifying the wording (if there are any other improvement suggestions with the same intent please provide them in an answer)

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced; a problem which would be resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers; or a simple typographical error**. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: I definitely support this.. as [Pekka once stated in an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315040/1324033) to an unrelated question - "we are trying to build something that benefits the world at large, not just the one person having the problem.".  This rewording would amplify a point of this close reason to make sure questions have a future purpose

Comment: can we get some examples of questions that would now (better?) fall under the modified close reason? Maybe intended, but... i could see this covering a very large number of questions that previously were closable under too localised, but were no longer closeable once that reason went away.

Comment: @KevinB - For example, this was just asked: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45765481/1026459 ... "Could someone please explain this Assignment Operator." 0/-2 votes on the post at this point, 0 close votes, 1 answer, 1 comment pointing to the mdn page for assignment operators, and 13 views. This is a good example of a question "specific to one person's lack of understanding of a basic language feature" which would benefit from the clarification here, and it was just asked. This is rather common, and given your experience here, I expect you are familiar with the pattern.

Comment: i mean, i don't disagree that there's a lot of questions out there of this form that are entirely useless to future visitors.. that's pretty much every debugging question. but... should those be closed? is closing the right tool? do we have enough users for being able to close those to make a meaningful dent in the problem? i'd argue continuing to downvote those is the better option rather than shoving these into the close queue to age away.

Comment: @KevinB - It depends on what the core issue being debugged is. Plenty of debugging questions are on topic given the right circumstance, and there are many which apply to a broader audience. I am not sure how we made the jump to every debugging question needs to be closed, but that is not the intent reflected here in the wording nor in spirit.

Comment: Relevant: [Resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348025/resolved-in-a-manner-unlikely-to-help-future-readers). This would just proliferate an already harmful and unsupported mentality around questions that are on-topic but you just don't like. A question being too basic is not a reason to close a question and should not be.

Comment: I should rephrase that, a question not being useful to future viewers is not a reason to close a question in and of itself. Typographical errors are off-topic because they are unarguably of no use to future viewers, but that cannot be said about other questions.

Comment: i think that was the main issue i had with the change. It seems like it's moving more than just typographical mistakes into the bucket for this close reason.

Comment: I have no idea where on Meta it is, but I once read a description that I think captures the essence of the close reason: "brain fart." Your suggestion would broaden it from that general idea significantly. We *should* be hesitant to use this close reason when the user had some kind of legitimate misunderstanding.

Comment: The proposed change in wording would actually be a change in closure policy. However, the way you have worded the question implies you were under the false impression that "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers" was a valid reason for closure in and of itself. Is it actually your desire to change policy? Or, was it only your desire to correct what you understood to be a discrepancy between policy and the wording in the close reason? Given that you, probably, have read the linked question/answer and determined what the policy actually is, are you wanting to continue this request?

Comment: @Makyen - A change in closure policy is not the interpretation I took. These questions should be closed, it even says so in the linked duplicate. "The target remains the same though: "face-palm" problems that no longer affect the asker **and whose solutions will never benefit anyone else.**" are the reason for this close reason. I feel that the wording does not support that, however, it is noted that since duplicate closure is the fastest kind, users should opt to try to find a canonical source such as "what does the `;` signify in c#?".

Comment: Do we also need to support these when there is no canonical? Should that question, valid for all the reasons stated above, really be the type of questions we want our experts and our enthusiasts to be solving day in and day out? No and no are the answer to both of those. This is a broken window policy in my opinion. That said, since the community views this issue as a duplicate of the other (which asked more about policy outlook) I will leave it closed and move on to other issues.